# asp.net sqldatasource parsing errors

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, sqldatasource

The sqldatasource is giving me parse errors and i can't figure out why. I should say i'm working on an old version of NopCommerce. This is the error message i'm getting:

**Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not have a public property named 'Type'.**

This is the code generating the error:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource Type="button" ID="CustomerSearch" class="adminButtonBlue" runat="server" OnClick="btnImportXLS_Click" ValidationGroup="ExportXLS" ConnectionString ="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString" %>"/>
```

Am i missing something in the sqldatasource-tag? Also, what is the purpose of the connectionstring and what should i put there, the same connaction name as in the connection.config file?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Kristoffer.  Was my answer helpful to you?  Do you still have questions about this?

Comment: Thanks think iv'e got it now =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation on [the SqlDataSource control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First off, there is no "Type" attribute.  So you'll need to remove that.  The SqlDataSource doesn't render a *visible* control at all, it's just for providing data / data operations to databound ASP.NET controls (like GridView,, FormView, etc).

For the same reason, you don't have / need Onclick, class, or ValidationGroup attributes.

This will not cause you parser errors:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CustomerSearch" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString ="<%$ ConnectionStrings:yourConnectionString" %>"/>
```

Where "yourConnectionString" above is a connection string name from your web.config file.

However, it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what this control is to be used for.  Check out this MSDN article for a great overview, and links to tutorials:

[SqlDataSource Web Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).